# MapQuest marker click listener and Infowindow using Mapquest direction API in android

Tags: android, mapquest

i'm using mapquest direction API and able to do alomost every operation with map like adding multiple markers, drawing a route between multiple markers and so on. but i'm stuck at **marker click Listener event** and **showing a infowindow** on click event. So please help me if there exist any work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the MapQuest JavaScript api, which will be deprecated in the near future, use the [MapQuest Leaflet plugins](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins) which is what MapQuest.com is using now. You can still add multiple markers, draw route highlights, and get better event handling on mobile devices.

Comment: i used leaflet api as well there are still some limitations in that api like using native app drawable icons for custom map markers and also camera zoom to the selected marker and so on. I guess Mapbox is a good option now that can replace google maps.

Comment: MapQuest's updated mobile sdks should be out late Q2.